# For a typical team of 20 .net developers how many sql developers and DBA's should be allocated?

Tags: sql-server, performance, project-management

For a typical team of 20 .net developers how many sql developers and DBA's should be allocated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it depends if the project is too-much data driven or not. For a typical project two sql developers and one DBA should be sufficient.

This too deviates depending the stage of the project i.e. development stage or maintenance stage. Its is generally seen that during the maintenance phase the demand for DBA's is more and in development phase the demand of sql developers is more.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional number is actually zero!

Comment: Then the .net developers would themselves be managing all the DB related operations. And when team size and cost of project is an issue this approach is followed.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with HotTester. It also depends on the software design the developers come up with. I can imagine that if they employ SQL stored procedures a lot (as opposed to solving issues in C#-space) you would require more sql developers.

Usually developers should not defer too much application logic to stored procedures though.

Easiest solution: ask your lead developer what he thinks :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much Database Administrative type work you need to perform, you may actually be better off outsourcing this function. The company I consult for, [Santech Solutions](http://www.santechsolutions.co.uk), provide this very service.

For SQL Development work however, you will most likely require on site full time resource available and so the previous posters recommendations stand.